# Асинхронный вывод без нарушения текущего ввода

Tags: java, консоль

Я создал второй поток, который выводит каждую секунду "Информацию",
моя проблема в том, когда вы печатаете команду в консоль, в это время второй поток может вывести информацию, которая в свою очередь появится прямо в строке ввода команды, тем самым мешая вводу. См. скрин.

[image: Вывод в строку ввода.]

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedCharsetException, IOException {
        new Thread2().start();
        while (true) {
            final String line = System.console().readLine("Enter command: ").toLowerCase();
            if (line.equals("test")) {
                System.out.println("YES!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            System.out.println("ИНФОРМАЦИЯ!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну консоль же одна. Курсор в ней один. Как вы хотите вывести информацию, пока юзер печатает?

Comment: Поле ввода команды - самая нижняя строка консоли. Весь вывод начинается со второй строки снизу, не затрагивая поле ввода. Описываю то, что видел сам.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен synchronized, он блокирует выполнения других потоков пока текущий поток не будет выполнен.

https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1992-mnogopotochnostjh-v-java-sutjh-pljusih-i-chastihe-lovushki-

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedCharsetException, IOException {
        new Thread2().start();
        synchronized (this) {
            while (true) {
                final String line = System.console().readLine("Enter command: ").toLowerCase();

                if (line.equals("test")) {
                    System.out.println("YES!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NO!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы потоки ввода и вывода происходили параллельно и не мешали друг другу. Чтобы вышло что-то вот такое:

Поле ввода команды - самая нижняя строка консоли. Весь вывод начинается со второй строки снизу, не затрагивая поле ввода. Уже видел такое когда-то.

Comment: @ДавидДегтярьов тогда вам нужна какая-нибудь библиотека текстового пользовательского интерфейса. Или библиотека управления консолью, типа [jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi), и реализовать TUI самостоятельно.

Comment: У меня есть идея: Что, если в событие вывода в консоль текста: 
1) Считать уже набранный текст с консоли
2) Сохранить его куда-то 
3) Закрыть ввод. 
После вывода "информации" в консоль Открыть ввод, и впихнуть туда ранее набранный текст.
Можно ли это реализовать таким способом? Я немного чайник.